# Get Selected Text from custom control in datagridview

Tags: c#, selectedtext

I have a datagridview. This datagridview has some columns. One of the  columns is hosting a custom control. In this custom control you can type similar to a textbox. Then I have implemented a mechanism to control what user can type: only digits and some special characters like backspace. Also I have limited the maximum length, p.e, to 10. So I have overrided the KeyPress method and inside it, I control what user is currently typing. All ok until here, the problem comes when user reaches the maximum length, so no digits and special character can be written as it has the maximum length but in this case, if user selects all the text, and then he types something when text is selected and length is the maximum,  I want to permit him to do that because as text is selected, when he types, the text will be deleted and it will remain the new character he has typed. So in this case, I need to know if all text is selected, and if so and length is maximum, I want to permit this. How can I get the text selected?

Comment: u did not mention technology u are using. is it WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, it is windows forms. I am using C# under Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: first of all I do not this u need to control max length while all text is selected as this behavior will always delete previews text
as far es selection part is concerned, there are tow properties u can use to check if text is selected. SelectionLength  and SelectedText.Length so if your custom control or whatever derives from TextBox u can access both of those properties.

Comment: but if the control does not derive from TextBox... is there any way to know if text is selected? I have tried to use clipboard using sendKeys.sendWait("^C"); but when doing this it hangs. Any ideas?

Comment: I can hardly imagine any control or reason to implement one like that which allows to type in something but does not implement basic TextBox behavior. why making things complicated when u can simply derive from TextBox and do whatever extra functionality u want?